# System Settings and sound missing

Tags: apt, sound, 17.10, pulseaudio, system-settings

I had a problem with my left audio front panel and I was trying to fix it. I searched for a solution for my problem in other sites and I execute a code to eliminate the pulse folder. However, the system settings and the control volume are missing now. I try to install gnome and `pavucontrol`. But the system returns the same message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing
```

P.S. My Ubuntu is 17.10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get update` first and then try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing`.

If the Problem ist still there, you should consider [upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) to a newer version of Ubuntu, since 17.10 is not longer maintained.

Comment: The commands sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get update --fix-missing didn't work. I installed the latest version of Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you accept this answer if it didn't work?